# How to specify the position of every plot in a multiple plot matrix?

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R and sorry in advance if my question is trivial.

I have 6 plots (A, B, C, D, E, F) and I would like to see them as a multiple plot, but I would like to set manually the position of every single plot in multiple plot matrix.

The following code/example will set the position of every single plot as follows: A[1,1]; B[1,2]; C[2,1]; D[2,2]; E[3,1]; F[3,2];...

```
par(mfrow=c(12,2))    #I would like to have 12 rows and 2 columns
plot(x=A,...)
plot(x=B,...)
plot(x=C,...)
plot(x=D,...)
plot(x=E,...)
plot(x=F,...)
```

Is there a function that I can add in front of plot() for each A, B, C, D, E, F..., which will define exact position of single plot in matrix?
In my case I would like to draw plots A, B and C in the first column (A[1,1]; B[2,1]; C[3,1]) and D, E and F in the second column (D[1,2]; E[2,2]; F[3,2])

I know that I could plot A, followed by D, B, E, C, F, to obtain the result, but I would like to set the position manually (A have a large number of individual plots that should be contained in the multiple plot).

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please have a look at `?layout`.